# Rails problem using I18n in views but not in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have to show a translation in a view in a locale different from the current one. I use this code to force the locale for one translation :

```
I18n.t :what_ever, :locale => 'es'
```

It works in the rails console but not in the view! I have try many things but I cannot find a solution. The view tell this error :

```
translation missing: es.what_ever
```

So, I was thinking it was a trouble from the YAML but exactly the same code works well in `rails console`....

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Using -> Rails 3.0.7, ruby 1.9.2

Comment: just a guess.. have you tried using a string instead of a symbol?

Comment: is your file newly created? if yes, have you restarted your server?

Comment: my fault, forget to reboot :(

Answer (score 3):

This seems like answered, but I will give you the solution anyway:

Instead of doing:

```
I18n.t :what_ever, :locale => 'es'
```

Do this:

```
I18n.t 'what_ever', :locale => 'es'
```